# In SwiftUI, how to scale content inside scrollView with dynamic changing scrolling area?

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I'm developing MacOS App with SwiftUI.

Let's say we have a fixed size window, which will show a scrollable image.
Now I want to create a feature which can let user to scale the image, and can scroll and view the scaled image inside the window.

The problem is, once I scaled up the image, the scroll area seems not expended together, and the scroll area is not big enough to reach each corner of the image.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical] , showsIndicators: true ){
            Image("test")
                .scaleEffect(2)
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
    }
}
```

I have tried to set the Image's frame by using GeometryReader, but got the same result.

MacOS 11.1, Xcode 12.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.scaleEffect` seems to perform a visual transform on the view without actually affecting its frame, so the `ScrollView` doesn't know to accommodate the bigger size.

`.resizable()` and `.frame` on the image seem to do the trick:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scale : CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical] , showsIndicators: true ){
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 300 * scale,height: 300 * scale)
            }
            .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
            Slider(value: $scale, in: (0...5))
        }
    }
}
```